# Proper Localhost Setup in MacOS Catalina

Tags: craft3

I installed Craft CMS in /Volumes/Drive2/WWW/Craft using command line process and successfully done.
But when sign-in in admin it will not proceed because it has error "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE".

I have already followed the instructions in v3.x installation document. And also the permissions for the folders/files, instead 774 I set them to 777 to make it run.

Is there other things to do or proper localhost setup to make it run smoothly with no errors?

In vhosts file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName craftcms.test
    ServerAlias craftcms.test
    DocumentRoot "/Volumes/Drive2/WWW/Craft/web"

    <Directory "/Volumes/Drive2/WWW/Craft">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In httpd file:

```
DocumentRoot "/Volumes/Drive2/WWW/"
<Directory "/Volumes/Drive2/WWW/">
    Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    MultiviewsMatch Any
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 2):

I can only recommend going with DDEV (see this here: https://craftcms.com/docs/getting-started-tutorial/install/). It's better than all other forms of setup.